# User Mode Linux - Installing a module error

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, user-mode-linux

I am trying to run 'make' on a module in User Mode Linux to install a simple makefile. Here is my make file:

```
obj-m    := hello.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

When I run this in User Mode Linux I get the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/2.6.28/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/2.6.28/build'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

The problem is that no files are present under `/lib/modules/`. There's no directory for 2.6.28 or build. From what I've read, these should be symlinks to `/usr/src`, but under `/usr/src`, I don't see any files under that either.

Answer (score 1):

Sources and headers of your UML kernel must be used to compile module for it.

You can compile it either inside UML or just in main system, but you must to use UML's kernel's headers and build scripts

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to compile in the main system and I have the full source tree in a directory in the main system that I 'make' and boot into for the UML instance. How do you use the UML's headers and build scripts from within the main system? Thanks again!

Comment: @Zach, just open a manual of creating linux kernel modules, and take a look in Makefiles and compilation options. Change the pathes to kernel.

Comment: @osgx, Thanks. For instance, the above makefile targets /lib/modules/2.6.28/build. If I were to compile this on my host, it would look at the host /lib/modules/2.6.28/build directory. How would I get it to look into the source tree that UML will be compiled from? I can't find the correlating directory to an uncompiled source that relates to /lib/modules/.......Know what I mean? I may not be making myself clear enough in my description.

Comment: change KDIR from `KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` to `KDIR := /home/Zach/kernels/uml/uml-2.6.36`

Comment: and add to make string `arch=um`

Answer (score 0):

You need to build and install the version of the kernel you are compiling for. Get the source from [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org), configure (I think `make menuconfig` picks the config up from the running kernel), build, and install it. You can do the build in your home directory under regular user, then of course you would need root to install it.

#### Edit:

Just in case you missed this - here's [User Mode Linux HOWTO](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/old/UserModeLinux-HOWTO.html). It contains specific items for building and installing kernel and modules. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do. I build and install linux 2.6.28 in UML. I then run ./linux to enter the UML instance and try to compile a module that I built for the UML instance. In my UML instance, I have no directory for lib/modules/.... and no directory for /usr/src/.... so the makefile above fails with the error above.

Comment: Hmm, not really familiar with UML. You probably can convince the kernel build to install into whatever directory the UML mounts.